# How to input store location for each product?

Tags: magento-1, delivery

We want to offer our online customers the possibility to have same day order delivery. But it will be available only if the customer is located 2/3 miles from the store that has the product they want to buy? (We have 5 physical stores)

For that, first of all, we need to input store location for each product. Where should I input this? is there the possibility in Magento Catalog to update product/store location( Address and Postcode) for each product?

Answer (score 2):

In order to put the location of your store, you can create a product attribute and  then assign with every products.

To create an attribute, go to **`Catalog  >  Attribute  >  Manage Attributes`** in admin. Next step is to assign this attribute to currently active `attribute set`. For this go to **`Catalog  >  Attributes  > Manage Attribute Sets`** and put your custom attribute to default attribute set that you are using for your products.

This will provide you a new provision to input store location via each product. My recommendation is use `select` type attribute. This will provide you a unique reference for each store and based on that reference, you can calculate the distance from store to the destination. In order to do this task, you probably need to create a custom module for it and hence it is kind of "out of box" topic for this question

I hope that will direct you to the right path.